# Raspberry Pi 4: cannot use 1920×1080 resolution on a Full HD monitor (Asus PA238)

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, screen, raspberry-pi-os

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB). I installed the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS (`2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-full.zip`) on it and plugged it on my 1080p TV, and everything worked as expected.

However, when I plug it to a PC monitor (Asus PA238, a 1920×1080@60Hz monitor), my monitor shows "OUT OF RANGE", and Raspberry Pi OS defaults to 1024×768 resolution. This PC monitor works perfectly fine in its nominal mode (1920×1080@60Hz) with my Linux desktop and my Linux laptop.

If I leave the `/boot/config.txt` file untouched, here is what I have with `tvservice`:

```
state 0x6 [DVI CUSTOM RGB full 4:3], 1024x768 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 17 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive 
           mode 6: 640x480 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:31MHz progressive 
           mode 8: 800x600 @ 56Hz 4:3, clock:36MHz progressive 
           mode 9: 800x600 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:40MHz progressive 
           mode 10: 800x600 @ 72Hz 4:3, clock:50MHz progressive 
           mode 11: 800x600 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:49MHz progressive 
           mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:65MHz progressive 
           mode 17: 1024x768 @ 70Hz 4:3, clock:75MHz progressive 
           mode 18: 1024x768 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:78MHz progressive 
           mode 21: 1152x864 @ 75Hz 4:3, clock:108MHz progressive 
           mode 32: 1280x960 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:108MHz progressive 
           mode 35: 1280x1024 @ 60Hz 5:4, clock:108MHz progressive 
           mode 36: 1280x1024 @ 75Hz 5:4, clock:135MHz progressive 
           mode 47: 1440x900 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:106MHz progressive 
           mode 58: 1680x1050 @ 60Hz 16:10, clock:146MHz progressive 
           mode 82: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 
           mode 85: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 18 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive 
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive 
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive 
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced 
           mode 14: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:54MHz x2 progressive 
           mode 15: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:54MHz x2 progressive 
  (prefer) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive 
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive 
           mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced 
           mode 29: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:54MHz x2 progressive 
           mode 30: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:54MHz x2 progressive 
           mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 
           mode 32: 1920x1080 @ 24Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
           mode 33: 1920x1080 @ 25Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
           mode 34: 1920x1080 @ 30Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
```

I've tried to edit the `config.txt` file to use

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

since it seems to be the "preferred" format, but I always end up with a 1024×768 screen. I've then tried

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
```

as well as a bunch of other modes (with different frequencies), but every time the same thing happens. I can see:

- the bootup screen (with the Raspberry Pi logo at the bottom left) briefly
- an underscore at the top left of the screen (that seems to match the configuration I've set in the config.txt file, i.e. it's smaller if I select Full HD resolution, and bigger if I select 640×480 type of resolution)
- a grey screen with the Raspberry Pi logo flashes at the middle of the screen
- another underscore at the bottom left
- my screen then goes blank and its on-screen display (OSD) shows "OUT OF RANGE"
- finally, Raspberry Pi OS GUI shows up in 1024×768.

I tried to use the "Screen Configuration" tool to select a different resolution (I have 5 choices: `1920×1080`, `1024×768`, `800x600`, `848×480` and `640×480`), and all the resolutions work **except the actual native one (1920×1080)!** There is only one frequency option available (60Hz).

If I use `edidparser`, here are the information I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tvservice -d asus_pa238_edid.dat
Written 256 bytes to asus_pa238_edid.dat
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ edidparser asus_pa238_edid.dat 
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing asus_pa238_edid.dat...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 51x29 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 50-75 Hz, horizontal is 24-83 kHz, max pixel clock is 170 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is ASUS_PA238
HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are B7 EF 00
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 6, 640x480p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 8, 800x600p @ 56 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 10, 800x600p @ 72 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 11, 800x600p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 17, 1024x768p @ 70 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 18, 1024x768p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 36, 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz in established timing I/II
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0xD1C0 B300 8140 8180 9500 81C0 714F 0101 
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 82, 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16:9) in standard timing 0
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 58, 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 1
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 32, 1280x960p @ 60 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 2
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 3
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 47, 1440x900p @ 60 Hz (16:10) in standard timing 4
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 85, 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (16:9) in standard timing 5
HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 21, 1152x864p @ 75 Hz (4:3) in standard timing 6
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:no, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:1
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 720x480p @ 60 Hz (2)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (4)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 50 Hz (19)
HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 720x576p @ 50 Hz (17)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 3, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 17, 720x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 18, 720x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 20, 1920x1080i @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 5, 1920x1080i @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 14, 1440x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 15, 1440x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 29, 1440x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 30, 1440x576p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 31, 1920x1080p @ 50Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz (native)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 32, 1920x1080p @ 24Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 33, 1920x1080p @ 25Hz 
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 34, 1920x1080p @ 30Hz 
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48|96 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 5
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no extension fields
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock unlimited MHz or h. blanking unlimited
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock -1224918860 MHz (score 25)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 66472)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 135592)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 149416)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (6) 640x480p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 31 MHz has a score of 5760
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (8) 800x600p @ 56 Hz with pixel clock 36 MHz has a score of 26880
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (9) 800x600p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 40 MHz has a score of 28800
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (10) 800x600p @ 72 Hz with pixel clock 50 MHz has a score of 8640
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (11) 800x600p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 49 MHz has a score of 9000
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (14) 1440x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 54 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (15) 1440x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 54 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz (score 5398248)
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (16) 1024x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 65 MHz has a score of 47185
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (17) 1024x768p @ 70 Hz with pixel clock 75 MHz has a score of 13762
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (18) 1024x768p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 78 MHz has a score of 14745
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 117160
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (20) 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 128680
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (21) 1152x864p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 43662
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (29) 1440x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 54 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (30) 1440x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 54 MHz has a score of 66472
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (31) 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 232360
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (32) 1920x1080p @ 24 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 124532
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (32) 1280x960p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 98728
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (33) 1920x1080p @ 25 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 128680
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (34) 1920x1080p @ 30 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 149416
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 103643
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (36) 1280x1024p @ 75 Hz with pixel clock 135 MHz has a score of 24576
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (47) 1440x900p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 106 MHz has a score of 102760
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (58) 1680x1050p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 146 MHz has a score of 130840
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (82) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 149416
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (85) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 80296
HDMI0:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edidparser exited with code 0
```

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that, for some reason, the data provided by the EDID of my monitor did not work properly on the Raspberry Pi.

I used the `hdmi_ignore_edid` field in the `config.txt` as detailed in [the documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md):

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

Then I could force the HDMI group and mode that matched the resolution of the monitor, namely:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
```

In the end, I followed the example given by user Milliways to have a dedicated section for my monitor in the `config.txt` file (so that if I plug the RPi to another monitor, it will still try to detect the best configuration based on EDID data):

```
[EDID=ASUS_PA238]
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_drive=2
```

Comment: "Then I could force the HDMI group and mode that matched the resolution of the monitor"

Okay, but how do you determine the HDMI group and mode for your particular monitor?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why yours doesn't work.

I use the following to force 1920x1080 when my Acer_KA210HQ is detected.

```
[EDID=ACR-Acer_KA210HQ]
#DVI DMT (82) RGB full 16:9, 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
[all]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4 lines seems to work perfectly for me:

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
hdmi_drive=2
```

As an alternative with a slightly lower resolution i had:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=51
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

For the corresponding hdmi_group and hdmi_mode see the following link:

```
https://www.scribd.com/document/519276699/raspberry-pi-4-HDMI
```